# Direct sum of primary decompositions vector spaces intersected with a T invariant subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, invariant-subspace

Here is the question:
[image]

I am stuck on this question for more than a few hours.
All my attempts to solve this question failed.

What I tried to do:

Show the following equality: $W = W \cap V = W \cap (W_1 \oplus W_2 ... \oplus W_k) = (W \cap W_1) \oplus ... \oplus (W \cap W_k)$

However, I couldn't manage to prove the last equality.

My next idea was to show that any $w \in W$ can be represented as a sum of k vector that belong to the intersections:
$w = w_1 + w_2 ... + w_k$ such that $w_i \in (W \cap W_i)$ but I couldn't figure out how to do it for all possible T invariant subspaces.

Lastly, I would appreciate it if somebody could give me a hint or point me towards an idea.
Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:

It seems a question very similar to this has already been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3241924/does-intersection-of-invariant-subspace-distribute-over-direct-sum-of-invariant?rq=1), and there is an existing answer in there.

Comment: The question is incorrect as stated. The claim is only true when the $W_i$ are direct sums of generalized eigenspaces of $T$, in which case you can use the fact that the associated projection operators for the $W_i$ are polynomials in $T$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4311648).

Comment: @blargoner After trying to find someone else who tackled this question, it seems that a mandatory requirement is that the minimal polynomial of T is the product of pairwise co-prime polynomials. Although even under that assumption, I couldn't figure out how to continue the proof.

Comment: You can always write the minimal polynomial as a product of pairwise coprime polynomials -- if $\mu=f_1^{k_1}\cdots f_r^{k_r}$ is the prime factorization, then the $g_i=f_i^{k_i}$ are pairwise coprime. I recommend going to the library and reading Greub *Linear Algebra*, 4th ed. Theorem I on p. 415.